# Error response when installing Shipyard: Bind for 0.0.0.0:2375 failed: port is already allocated

Tags: docker

I meet the problem when running the deploy sh of Shipyard. The error is

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint shipyard-proxy (): Bind for 0.0.0.0:2375 failed: port is already allocated.

[image: The error in deployment]
Then I use `netstat -ntple` command to find out who is listening port 2375.

The result is dockerd itself.

[image: Please click here to see the screenshot]

So I wonder how to overcome this problem in order to finish the installation of Shipyard.

And here is the `docker ps`

[image: docker ps]

My `docker info` result is showed below

```
Containers: 8
Running: 4
Paused: 0
 Stopped: 4
Images: 21
Server Version: 17.12.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9b55aab90508bd389d7654c4baf173a981477d55
runc version: 9f9c96235cc97674e935002fc3d78361b696a69e
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.13.0-37-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 962.8MiB
Name: flora-virtual-machine
ID: J765:X2HP:UL4S:2SCV:7CZK:LG63:4H5V:QFDF:RUM5:2F2Y:XC6I:Y3AE
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Registry Mirrors:
 http://4d7846d0.m.daocloud.io/
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: What id the output of `docker ps` and output of `docker info`. Please add it to your question, don't answer the same in comments

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!